# ビジネスプロセス管理(BPM)プラットフォームActivitiにて、アプリのデプロイからプロセスの実行～完了までactivitiのREST APIで実現する方法

Tags: java, spring

## 実現したいこと

オープンソースのビジネスプロセス管理(BPM)プラットフォームActivitiにて
アプリのデプロイからプロセスの実行～完了までactivitiのREST APIで実現する方法。

## 試したこと

#### 1.アプリをデプロイ(Publish・公開)

restの「POST repository/deployments」を実行↓
`「curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -H "Authorization: Basic a2VybWl0Omtlcm1pdA==" -F "file=@/home/masaki/tmp/activiti/bpmn/___.bpmn20.xml" http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/repository/deployments」`

#### 2.デプロイしたアプリのプロセス定義情報を取得

restの「GET /repository/process-definitions」を実行

#### 3.プロセスインスタンスの作成

上記「2」で取得したプロセスのprocessDefinitionIdを指定してrestの「POST runtime/process-instances」を実行。
→ここでact_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムにrest実行時のユーザでない値が入ってしまう。「1」をrestではなくactivitiの画面上でデプロイ実施した場合はact_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムにrest実行時のユーザが入ることを確認しました。

#### 4.act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの変更

restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にdelegateを指定、assignee属性に「3」のプロセスインスタンス作成時を実行した際のユーザを設定して実行。
act_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムの値が変更されることを確認。

#### 5.タスクの完了

restの「POST runtime/tasks/{taskId} 」でrequestbodyのaction属性にcompleteを指定して実行。
response code=500で「A delegated task cannot be completed, but should be resolved instead.」とエラーになる。

Comment: `A delegated task cannot be completed, but should be resolved instead.` は、「委任されたタスクは complete` 出来ないので、代わりに `resolve` してください」というエラー ( https://github.com/flowable/flowable-engine/blob/main/modules/flowable5-engine/src/main/java/org/activiti/engine/impl/persistence/entity/TaskEntity.java#L186-L190 )です。しかし、原因は `3. プロセスインスタンスの作成`における 「ここでact_ru_taskテーブルのassignee_カラムにrest実行時のユーザでない値が入ってしまう。」にありそうです。ここの解決するには、今質問文にある内容だけだと多分情報が足りなさそうです。